# WebClient.DownloadData() - Exception: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document

Tags: xml, webclient, dtd

When I use WebClient.DownloadData() to download file, it occurs an error that "For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method."

```
private static byte[] DownloadAttachment(WebClient client, string uri)
{
    return client.DownloadData(uri);
}
```

I just use it to download a word document from the Office 365 SharePoint site. The webClient object property setting would like:

```
webClient.Credentials = GlobalData.SharePointOnlineCredentials;
webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
```

Can you help me? I searched many questions and answers, but all of them are about XmlReaderSettings. But I just only one download sentence, there is no XmlReaderSettings. Please help me!

Comment: Anybody can help me ?